# green screen after switching HDMI channels Ubuntu 20.04 (4k Samsung monitor)

Tags: 20.04, hdmi

I have 2 PCs connected to my monitor, one of then running Ubuntu 20.04 and FF in kiosk mode, playing slides (revo slider)

When I switch to the other HDMI channel for some time and then switch back to the Ubuntu HDMI port, all I see is a dark green screen of death.

It seems if I stay focussed on the Ubuntu HDMI channel, this does not happen.

I have no idea where even to start looking.

GPU: Radeon VEGA Mobile Gfx
Drivers: included in Ubuntu 20.04 latest

How can I check the drivers?

Dont find this on google

Any idea?

THx
Dan

Comment: Sounds like your graphics driver broke. Do you see a "stacktrace" with `dmesg` (usually starts with "---cut here ---" ) But it is rather like looking into a milky glasbowl: What graphics card you have and which drivers are installed? Check all three and **edit** your question and fill in the missing infos

Comment: How are you switching?